# Edit several values in fields

Tags: php

I have this query that display two inputs values because id field is found twice in table.

```
 <form action="edit_batch.php" method="post" > 
$sql="select Batch_Name from claims_follow_up.batch where id='$id'"; 
 $req=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die("Erreur d'execution");
while($tab=mysqli_fetch_array($req))
 {              
 ?>
 <label>Batch Name</label> 
 <input type="text" name= "batch" value='<?=$tab['Batch_Name']?>' required><br>
  <?php 
   }
  ?>
</form>
```

I would like to edit those values but i fail, Here how i try:

edit_batch.php

```
 include_once('connection.php');
$batch=mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['batch']); 
$belong=intval($_POST['belong']);
 $sql = "update claims_follow_up.batch  set Batch_Name='$batch' where belong='$belong'";
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UPDATE syntax does not include the VALUES keyword.

Check the reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

VALUES is used for INSERT.

Comment: thanks so much my mistake i correct it, it still not working

Comment: anybody can help me ?

Comment: can you get the actual sql error message, please? Otherwise it's really difficult to guess what's going wrong

Comment: the error is when i have 2 input fields that display in the while and  i edit one, the edit is made in both of them

Comment: the two input fields have the same name, and besides, you read only one single value from the $_POST array, and run one single query to update both records, so it obviously update both with the same name. Also I don't get where the "belong" value is coming from..

Comment: the belong value is ok, as you said the update is done, but how to change the name so that changes make properly. My issue is the fact the (while) can show several inputs. How to update those inputs ?